# How to allow image tagging with least privileges

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am using this IAM policy to allow a user to tag images with the least privileges possible.

However, it does not seem to be enough

```
{   
    "Version" : "2012-10-17",   
     "Statement" : [{      
        "Effect" : "Allow",      
        "Action" : [ 
        "ec2:CreateTags", 
        "ec2:DescribeTags", 
        "tag:getResources"
        "tag:getTagKeys",
        "tag:getTagValues",
        "tag:addResourceTags"
    ],
       "Resource" : "arn:aws:ec2:::image/*"      
    }] 
 }
```

Also, is there a way to run AWS CLI so that it is more verbose at to the specific IAM permissions that it needs to use?

Answer (score 2):

There is a syntax error after `getResources`. The following works perfectly for me:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:DescribeTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The resource has to be **" * "** since `CreateTags` and `DeleteTags` actions do not support resource-level permissions. Policies granting access must specify **" * "** in the resource element.